# Temporary disabling a partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, windows

I have a dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 - Windows 10 using Legacy.

I want to temporary disable Linux since the chain booting prevents Windows from updating the PC.

I'm pretty sure that the problem is the Grub since [other users](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/error-message-something-happened-sorry-were-having/2624ce37-8ec7-4144-8573-5f207792458c) have found the same issue... The problem is that the person on that forum had Windows and Linux installed on different drives, so by disabling one or simply prioritizing the other one inside the BIOS would have directly used the Windows bootloader.

Since I have Windows and Ubuntu installed on different partitions of the same disk, I cannot disable one of them, and for some reasons just setting the Windows partition as active does not solve the problem (GRUB just keeps getting prioritized).

So, is there a way to temporary disable a partition without deleting it? Uninstalling GRUB would be a it too much since I wouldn't have access to Ubuntu after the update, so I need a method which is reversible from Windows...

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT:

Another thing I THINK could help is temporary setting windows as boot option using Grub Rescue.

So after I type c inside the grub page, I should type something like this:

```
ls
boot=(hd0,msdos1)
prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

But for Windows.

This is taken from [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/a8UuIBdMh4M) which says how to select the bootloader when it cannot be found, but it shows the way to select the Ubuntu bootloader... I couldn't find a way to select the Windows one!

disclaimer: Maybe this hypothesis does not make sense... It was just to provide some food for thought.

Comment: Think I would try upgrading from a Win 10 USB instead of from Win 7.  Backup all data you do not want to lose first and have Ubuntu USB handy.  Remember to backup all data.

Comment: @crip659 I already have Win 10... I want to update it from 1809 to 20H2 since the former is no longer supported

Comment: Updating from USB still an idea, think there is no way to disable a partition before booting, besides deleting it.  Would also try question on other sites that have more Windows users, since this is more Window problem not liking change.  There should be a way to remove/disable grub, but it could lead to more nasty problems and is way above what I know and will probably need USBs for Ubuntu and Windows to fix.

Comment: Adding exact error to question might help, googling it also.  Only thing I found is system reserve might be too full, but might not help if your problem is another error type.